# Prove that $C([0,1]),||.||)$ with $||x||= \text{sup}_{t \in [0,1]}|tx(t)|$ is not complete using equivalence of norms

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Prove that $C([0,1]),||.||)$  with $||x||= \text{sup}_{t \in [0,1]}|tx(t)|$ is not complete

In https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3908897/edit I presented this exercise solved as in my lecture notes: by taking a Cauchy sequence and proving that it does not converges to something that is not in $C([0,1]),||.||)$. I 've made another solution inspired in other proofs I've seen and I'd like to know if it is correct and ask you some doubts about which where the same I had in the inspiration of the proof

Try: If I can proof this norm is not equivalent to the ||.||∞ norm, that means that the space C([0,1]),||.||) is not complete.

In $0 \leq t \leq 1 $   $|tf(t)| \leq |f(t)|$ so $||f(t)|| \leq ||f(t)||_{\infty}$

Now the question is if there exists an $c>0$ such that  $||f(t)||_{\infty} \leq c||f(t)||$

We take a sequence defined as follows:

$$ f_n(t)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{ t} && ,\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq 1 \\ n &&, 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}  \end{cases}   $$

$||f_n||_{\infty}= \text{sup}_{t \in [0,1]} |f_n(t)|=n$
$||f_n||=\text{sup}_{t \in [0,1]} |t f_n(t)|=\text{max} \{\text{sup}_{0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}} |t f_n(t)|,\text{sup}_{\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq 1} |t f_n(t)| \}=\text{max} \{\text{sup}_{0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}} nt,\text{sup}_{\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq 1} \frac{1}{t}t \}= \text{max} \{1,1\}=1 $

Then $\frac{||f_n||_{\infty}}{||f_n||} \to \infty$, when $n \to \infty$. So the norms are not equivalent

My questions are, in addition to knowing if this is correct :

1. In this approach I don't need the sequence to be Cauchy, right?.  in order to prove tht no such c exists , why do we consider a sequence in the first place? what's the idea?
2. Why do they take the limit of $\frac{||f_n||_{\infty}}{||f_n||} \to \infty$ at the end, how  does this proves that no constant c exists that makes the norms equivalent ?

Comment: Why would "not equivalent to the $L^\infty$ norm" imply incompleteness? ($L^1$ is complete...)

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich : what does $L^1$ has to do with all this? I am using this theorem: If $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2$ are any two norms in a Banach space: $(X, ||.||_1)$ is complete iff  $(X, ||.||_2)$ is complete

Comment: @David C. Ullrich I don't understand why wouldn't it be correct. I am following an example from a lecture almost identically, the only difference being the space was in that case  $C([-1,1]), ||.||)$ with $||f||=\text{sup}_{-1 \leq t \leq 1} (1-t^2)|f(t)|$

Comment: Why wouldn't it be correct? It's _not_ correct; a norm doesn't have to be equivalent to the $L^\infty$ norm to be complete. The argument in those notes may be correct; if so it's correct for reasons you haven't shared with us.

Comment: The "theorem" you say you're using is obviously false.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich the theorem I cited is not for a Banach space X, but more generally for any normed space X. It is from Rynne, Youngson - Linear Functional Analysis-2nd edition I pasted here so you can check it. Does it look wrong?

Comment: The theorem you pasted is not the theorem from your question that I pointed out is false! The correct (trivial) theorem talks about two _equivalent_ norms; the two norms in your problem are not equivalent, so you can't apply that theorem. (And yes, the theorem that you _stated_ is still false.)

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich The only theorem I have stated is the one I just pointed out, which one are you referring to?

Comment: Oh. The problem is with the _logic_. The correct theorem says that if two norms are equivalent and one is complete then the other is complete. It does _not_ say that if two norms are not equivalent and one is complete then the other is not complete (which is what it would need to say to make your application correct.)

Comment: Ok, but they used it like that in my lecture, unless I am miss interpreting . I will type the exact question an let you know in a while

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich Ok I know what I was doing wrong, I was using a problem in which the actual question was to prove the non-equivalence of the  norms  and making that logic error in the theorem, I was mistakenly using it to prove incompleteness .. So I can't prove incompleteness that way, right? Thanks for making me see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove that $(C([0,1]),||.||)$ is not complete by comparing the norm $||f||=\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}|tf(t)|$ with the usual norm $||f||_{\infty}$ but first let me answer to your questions:

1. No, you dont need to show that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in neither of two norms in order to show that there is no constant $c>0$ such that
   $$\tag{1}||f||_{\infty}\leq c||f||$$

We consider the sequence $(f_n)$ because it has the property that $||f_n||=1$ whereas $||f_n||_{\infty}=n$. In other words, we are trying to find some elements $f_n$ that belong to both spaces such that the norm $||f_n||_{\infty}$ is big whereas the norm $||f_n||$ is small so that we make $(1)$ fail.

2. Now, as you said, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{||f_n||_{\infty}}{||f_n||}\to \infty$ but we dont have necessarily have to take the limit in order to prove that $(1)$ is false. To see this, if there was some $c>0$ with
   $$||f||_{\infty}\leq c||f||$$
   for every $f$, then in particular, for the $f_n's$ we would have that $n\leq c$ for every $n$, which leads us to a contradiction.

Now why the non-equivalance of the two above norms implies that $(C([0,1]),||.||)$ is not complete its because of the open mapping theorem.

To see this, take the identity operator $I:(C([0,1]),||.||_{\infty})\to (C([0,1]),||.||)$ with $I(f)(t)=f(t)$ for $f\in C([0,1])$ and $0\leq t\leq 1.$

Since $||f||\leq ||f||_{\infty}$ it follows that $I$ is continuous, one to one and onto. Now, if $C([0,1])$ was complete with the norm $||f||=\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}|tf(t)|$, then, by the open mapping theorem
$$I^{-1}:(C([0,1]),||.||)\to (C([0,1],||.||_{\infty})$$
would also be continuous.  But this is equivalent to the existence of some $c>0$ that satisfies $(1)$ which you have shown there cant be such $c>0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on  a couple of thinks:1) How do you prove that $I$ is continuous, one to one and onto using $||f||<||f||_{\infty} ? 2 $) why is the last  continuity of $I^{-1}$  equivalent to the existence of c>1 that verifies (1).

Comment: I was looking for the theorem you are mentioning, According to wikipedia, what you are using is not exactly the open mapping theorem but a consequence of it : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)#Consequences.  What do you think?

Comment: Yes you are right, its a consequence of the mapping theorem, but its almost an immediate one. The big tool over here is the open mapping theorem, thats why i mentioned it. To answer to your questions in  your first comment, $I$ is one to one and onto because its just the identity operator. Now, to why $I$ is continuous is because of the following characterization of continuity in the context of linear operators. I.e. a linear operator $T:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if there is some $M>0$ such that $||Tx||_Y\leq M||x||_X$. Now can you see why $I^{-1}$ cant be continuous?

Comment: Since we need Banach spaces to talk about operators, I think that the paragraph you wrote "Since $||f||\leq ||f||_{\infty}$ it follows that $I$ is continuous, one to one and onto. Now, if $C([0,1])$ was complete with the norm $||f||=\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}|tf(t)|$, then, by the open mapping theorem...."  should have the sentences swapped:  ". If $C([0,1])$ was complete with the norm $||f||=\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}|tf(t)|$,  then since $||f||\leq ||f||_{\infty}$ it follows that $I$ is continuous, one to one and onto  by the open mapping theorem...."

Comment: I mean first we have to make the hypothesis of having a complete space, then we can check if the linear operator is continuous.

Comment: I forgot a period two comments above :   ".... it follows that I is continuous, one to one and onto.  By the open mapping theorem...."

Comment: And something else I haven't done operators yet, but I think I heard we need Hilbert spaces for that, but we have no scalar products here so I am kind of dubious about the validity of the approach

Comment: $T:X\to Y$ makes sense as a linear map when $X,Y$ are both vector spaces, you dont necessarily need inner product (or Hilbert space). In this example we have $X=Y=C([0,1])$. Check that $C([0,1])$ is a vector space. Now, to talk about continuity of $T$ you need a topology in both $X,Y$ (you dont need a Banach space necessarily). Since, both $||.||_{\infty},\ ||.||$ are norms in $C([0,1])$ they induce two topologies in the same space, by showing that these two norms aren't equivalent we showed that these topologies cant be the same.

Comment: ok, no Hilbert spaces and inner product are required, but from the wikipedia link, the spaces must be Banach, so is not enough to say that T makes sense as a linear map between vector spaces, which takes me back to my first remark ... :

Comment: ...about the swapping of the sentences, do you agree?. First we do the supposition that C[0,1] with the newly defined norm, then we can apply the open mapping theorem

Comment: We need Banach spaces in order to use the open mapping theorem, not to talk about the continuity of the operator. In general, we can have a non Banach space $X$ and $T:X\to X$ to be continuous. Wikipedia talks about banach spaces because of the open mapping theorem but if you look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator the definition of continuous linear operator is given in the more general context where $X,Y$ are just normed spaces, not necessarily complete.